# How to use Text to speech code with Text view only

Tags: java, android, button, text-to-speech

I've tried to do the Text to Speech tutorials online but instead it gave me an out put of typing the words and clicking a button to speak the typed words.

What I really want for my output is that the app would just read the text showed on the app example, It will read the text "I am Happy" which the string is already declared as TextView.

Here is a picture of an example of what I want to do.

[Link of picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcNI5.jpg)

When you press the speaker button it will just read the words above it.

Here is my java file which is still on typing the words and it gives out the speech:

```
 package com.example.chadymaebarinan.emojiexpress;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.util.Locale;

 public class Speech extends AppCompatActivity implements      OnClickListener,OnInitListener {

private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
private TextToSpeech myTTS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_speech);

    Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speak);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
    checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //handle user clicks here
    EditText enteredText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
    speakWords(words);

}

private void speakWords(String speech) {
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}

public void onInit(int initStatus) {
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `textView` in your xml with id say `myword` and remove the `editText` from xml

then instead of

```
public void onClick(View v) {
//handle user clicks here
EditText enteredText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter);
String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
speakWords(words);

 }
```

do

```
public void onClick(View v) {
//handle user clicks here
TextView myword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myword);
String words = myword.getText().toString();
speakWords(words);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

here this code working properly for me:
implement in user click :

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //handle user clicks here 
    EditText enteredText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    String words = enteredText.getText().toString();
    if(words.length!=0){
    StartSpeak(words);
     }
   }
```

Start a method before speak:

```
    private void StartSpeak(final String data) {

        TTS=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onInit(int initStatus) {
                        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            if(TTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                                TTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                            TTS.setPitch(1.3f);
                             TTS.setSpeechRate(0.7f);
                           // start speak
                            speakWords(data);
                        }
                        else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                     }


                  });
    }
```

Start Text to Speech

```
private void speakWords(String speech) {
        TTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```